# Turning off "storage full" warning

Tags: storage, huawei, system-error, 8.0-oreo

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

```
Storage almost full
```

OK, nice of you to warn me, I'll take care of that later.

```
Storage almost full
```

OK, good to have a reminder.

```
Storage almost full
```

I guess I could have forgotten twice?

```
Storage almost full
```

Seriously though, do I really have to see it pop up ELEVEN TIMES during the span of a 10:46 Youtube video? Huawei p10 lite with Android 8.0.0 and EMUI 8.0.0 here. Isn't there a way to turn it off until I get to free up some space?

Comment: We can understand your frustration but please don't let that be expressed in objectionable language. You wouldn't want your post to be closed as *rude*

Comment: Try disabling notifications for SystemUI and/or Android System apps.

Comment: You can also try to disable notifications for "My files" app by opening its settings --> notifications, then uncheck `Low storage` option.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I think there's no such thing as "My files" on Huawei. At least, I most definitely can't find it. Searching for System UI under settings gives no results, and System Apps sends me to Special Access.

Comment: When you go to Settings --> Apps, there are no Android System and SystemUI?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Under Settings/Apps&Notifications/Apps I do have System UI (with the blank space), but not Android System. What I said before was about the search bar in the Settings app not returning anything for the query "System UI".

Comment: Next time that obnoxious warning pops up, I'll try disabling System UI notifs.

Comment: My mistake. It is `System UI` not `SystemUI`

Answer (score 2):

Search "notifications" in the settings, select the notification access, then draw over other apps, find the phone manager and turn it off  bam the annoying pop-up is gone.

Just leaving this here for people who search how to fix this, found about it myself while trying to solve the problem on my Huawei when websites didn't have the solution.

For me the warning begins to pop-up when I have less than 100mb left in my internal storage and it won't go away until I delete something. It's very annoying when watching a video and it bothers you every 20 something seconds.

You can even remove the icon in the status bar by going to apps, finding the phone manager, clicking on the notifications and disabling Display in the status bar!

Comment: Thank you. My neighbor has an old phone, and this drove her crazy, and there's nothing she could do about it, since updates are forced onto the phone but storage is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I do have such warning whenever my phone storage is below 600mb. I don't think there is any possible solution to stop the warning from popping up whenever you're making use of your phone. But I'll recommend you get a cleanup application. I'm using an infinix hot 5 and it comes with XManager. Whenever I receive such warning, what I usually do is  make use of the cleanup option in the XManager to get data of what is eating up my memory space. After scanning you'll get to see what you don't need. After determining that you can go ahead and delete things you don need to free up your space. That's I would recommend you to do for until there is a better solution